# How can I print data in a way that consumes local variables when an assert fails in Rust?

Tags: testing, rust, assert

I have some tests which have some variables that hold some important data and I'd like to print their data when an assertion fails. Getting the data I need consumes the variables, so the printing code must own the variables. In this example, I'd want to call `dump_foo_data` once an assertion fails:

```rust
struct Foo();

fn dump_foo_data(f: Foo) {
    eprintln!("Behold, Foo data: ");
}

#[test]
fn my_test() {
    let f = Foo();
    eprintln!("begin");

    // do a test
    &f;
    let success = true;
    assert!(success);

    // do another test
    &f;
    let success = false;
    assert!(success);
}
```

I can make a very bad solution by making `dump_foo_data` non-returning and panic:

```rust
fn dump_foo_data(f: Foo) -> ! {
    eprintln!("Behold, Foo data: ");
    panic!();
}
```

Then instead of using `assert!`, I check the failure with an `if` and maybe call `dump_foo_data`:

```rust
    let success = true;
    if !success {
        dump_foo_data(f);
    }
```

This is too many lines of code, and I need to specify `f`. In reality, I have more than one variable like `f` that I need to dump data from, so it's not very nice to list out single relevant local variable in every check.

I couldn't figure out how to write a macro to make this better because I'd still need to pass every relevant local variable to the macro.

I couldn't think of a way to use `std::panic` either. `update_hook` would need to take ownership of `f`, then I couldn't use it in tests.

Is there any good way to do this in Rust?

Edit: I've thought of another approach: put each relevant local in an `Rc` then pass each of those to `std::panic::update_hook`. I've not confirmed whether this'll work yet.

Edit 2: Maybe I could abuse `break` to do what I explained with `goto` in a comment.

Comment: How do you expect to take ownership of a subset of the local variables without explicitly listing them?

Comment: Why can't your printing code just take references?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't know what to expect the Rust answer to be. Perhaps it's impossible. In C you could do this with a goto. You make a label to a call to `dump_foo_data` at the end of the test, then `goto` it in the true arm of the `if`. Or just write a macro that has the names of the relevant locals hard-coded and be careful to always use the same names.

Comment: @tadman Because the data I need can't be obtained from a reference. I have a `std::process::Child` and on it I call `kill` then `wait_with_output`. `wait_with_output` can't take a reference.

Comment: If the assert! macro doesn't do what you need, create your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution without macro or interior mutability and that doesn't require you to list all the variables on each check. It is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55756926/5397009):

```
struct Foo();

fn dump_foo_data(_f: Foo) {
    eprintln!("Behold, Foo data: ");
}

#[test]
fn my_test() {
    let f = Foo();
    let doit = || -> Option<()> {
        eprintln!("begin");
    
        // do a test
        &f;
        let success = true;
        success.then_some(())?;
    
        // do another test
        &f;
        let success = false;
        success.then_some(())?;
        
        Some(())
    };
    
    if let None = doit() {
        dump_foo_data (f);
        panic!("Test failure");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=809ed2a3b358f178b791959d6b888e5d)

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't know you could use `?` like that.

Answer (score 2):

One way that doesn't use any macro or shared-interior-mutability-reference magic might be to repossess `f`:

```
fn check_or_dump(success: bool, f: Foo) -> Foo {
   match success {
     true => f,
     false => panic!("Behold foo data: {:?}", dump_foo_data(f)),
   }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
let f = Foo();
let success = true;
let f = check_or_dump(success, f);
let success = false;
let f = check_or_dump(success, f);
// and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly better than needing to mess with a macro. Though there's still the issue of needing to specify `f` each time, maybe that's inevitable.

Comment: Thanks to macro hygiene, you probably even have to do that with macros.

Comment: Yep. I'm trying my utmost to find a way around it though haha.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a solution using the panic handler:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{Cell, RefCell};
use std::panic::PanicInfo;

thread_local! {
    static TL_PANIC_TARGETS: RefCell<Vec<Rc<dyn PanicTrigger>>> = RefCell::new(vec![]);
}

pub trait PanicTrigger {
    fn panic_trigger(self: Rc<Self>);
}

pub fn register_panic_trigger<P: PanicTrigger + 'static>(p: Rc<P>) {
    TL_PANIC_TARGETS.with(|v: _| {
        v.borrow_mut().push(p.clone());
    });
}

#[ctor::ctor]
fn set_panic_hook() {
    let old_hook = std::panic::take_hook();
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(move |pi: &PanicInfo| {
        run_panic_triggers(pi);
        old_hook(pi);
    }));
}

fn run_panic_triggers(_: &PanicInfo) {
    TL_PANIC_TARGETS.with(|v: _| {
        for pt in v.take() {
            pt.panic_trigger();
        }
    });
}

struct Foo();

fn dump_foo_data(_f: Foo) {
    eprintln!("Behold, Foo data: ");
}

impl PanicTrigger for Cell<Option<Foo>> {
    fn panic_trigger(self: Rc<Self>) {
        if let Some(f) = self.take() {
            dump_foo_data(f);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn my_test() {
    let f = Rc::new(Cell::new(Some(Foo())));
    register_panic_trigger(f.clone());

    let success = true;
    assert!(success);

    let success = false;
    assert!(success);
}

fn main() { }
```

Basically, you put the relevant data in an `Rc` and keep a local reference and put one in TLS for the panic handler. You need to put it in an `Option` in a `Cell` so that you can move out of it.

Types that don't need to be owned to print relevant data can be registered too, and you don't need to implement `PanicTrigger` on a `Cell<Option<T>>`, just `T`.

This is thread-safe.

Because the data is so wrapped up, it's harder to manipulate in the test body. But now you can use normal `assert!`. It's a trade-off.